# Create UIImage from a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I create a `UIImageView` with two `UILabel` as subviews of it:

```
 UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    img.backgroundColor=self.view.backgroundColor;

    UILabel *textOne=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 250)];
    textOne.text=_textOneLabel.text;
    textOne.textColor=_textOneLabel.textColor;

    UILabel *textTwo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,180,200,100)];
    textTwo.text=_textTwoLabel.text;
    textTwo.textColor=_textTwoLabel.textColor;

    [img addSubview:textOne];
    [img addSubview:textTwo];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img.image, nil, nil, nil); //img.image is null
```

I want to create a `UIImage` to save it in the camera roll with the `UIImageView` and the 2 created `UILabel`. `img.image` returns null because there is no image assigned to the `UIImageView`.

Do you have an idea of how achieving that?

Comment: Are you trying to burn text on image?

Comment: You haven't added any image to image view's image property, you only have specified its background color property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below method to convert your UIImageView to UIImage.

```
UIImage *image = [self ChangeImageViewToImage:img];
```

//Method

```
-(UIImage *) ChangeImageViewToImage : (UIImageView *) view{

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
 [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

 UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return img;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer, however, I have a small problem, is that the image is a little bit blurred. Can I optimize it?

Comment: Use the code I updated just now. It will give you retina image

Comment: Try this: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

Comment: I tried in my iPhone, and not in the simulator, and the image is not blurred. Well, you made my day Mavericks. Thank you very much. Accepted ;).

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
/* Creates an image with a home-grown graphics context, burns the supplied string into it. */
- (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[img drawInRect:aRectangle];

[[UIColor redColor] set];           // set text color
NSInteger fontSize = 14;
if ( [text length] > 200 ) {
    fontSize = 10;
}
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize];     // set text font

[ text drawInRect : aRectangle                      // render the text
         withFont : font
    lineBreakMode : UILineBreakModeTailTruncation  // clip overflow from end of last line
        alignment : UITextAlignmentCenter ];

UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
return theImage;
}
```

Comment: I already have the texts(UILabels) with the font, I just want to save the UIImageView + the 2 created UILabels into one UIImage.

Comment: That is what this function will do. You need to tweak the function a bit to take in as many `UILabels` and `UIImageView`you want.