# convert uiimage view to uiimage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MapViewPlus, imageFor annotation: AnnotationPlus) -> UIImage {

    let image: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "basic_annotation_image.png")
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4

    // Now i want to convert this imageView to UIImage

    return UIImage(named: "basic_annotation_image.png")!
}
```

I want to convert **UIImageView to UIImage**. Anyone know that how to do that?[enter image description here]

Comment: Never post code as image. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create UIImage from a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719518/create-uiimage-from-a-uiimageview)

Comment: Also see: [How to convert a UIView to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert UIImageView to UIImage, but you can use the image from the UIImageView:

```
let image: UIImage = yourImageView.image
```